# Get variable in scope without closure / wrapping function

Tags: javascript, php, scope, closures

If I have a variable that is changing over time and I want to preserve a particular instance of it I have to wrap it in a closure like so:

```js
function test(){
 var x = Math.random();
 // Is there an alternative to using the following closure:
 var printnum = (function(num){ 
  return function(){
   console.log(num);
  }
 })(this.x); // Because I think this is ugly
 
 return printnum;
}

var a = test();
var b = test();

a(); //number
a(); //same as above
b(); //different number
b(); //same as above
```

In PHP you would use `use` like so:

```
$a = rand();
function () use ($a) {
  echo($a);
}
```

I really appreciate this because you immediately see which variable is being injected, it's not listed at the very bottom like in js: `(function(b){})(a);` Also there aren't an excessive amount of brackets. I tried experimenting with `.apply()` and `.call()` and but they both execute the function, I just want to inject a variable in a certain state.

I think I'm just asking for a language feature that doesn't exist, but please prove me wrong. Any ideas?

Comment: Everyone offered very valuable input and I wish I could give you all the mark. You've all demonstrated many ways to achieve the same thing, thank you.

Comment: The question no longer makes any sense with `this.x` in it, and the answers don't fit the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you use es6? If so, an arrow function will give the same result, but is more concise:

```js
function test(){
 var x = Math.random();
  
 var printnum = x => () => console.log(x);
 return printnum(x);
  
    // OR you can invoke immediately:
    // var printnum = (x => () => console.log(x))(x);
    // return printnum;
}

var a = test();
var b = test();

a(); //number
a(); //same as above
b(); //different number
b(); //same as above
```

AFAIK, in javascript, you'll have to pass the `x` into the function one way or another to avoid it printing something else if `x`'s value is later changed.

Comment: I gave you the accepted for this: 'AFAIK, in javascript, you'll have to pass the x into the function one way or another'. Thank you. Good example of es6.

Answer (score 2):

a simple way using .bind() (ES5) to remove the wrapper functions and avoid closure:

```
function test(){
  return console.log.bind(console, Math.random());
}
```

Comment: Thank you. You've proven that there is a way to achieve this without a closure. I forgot about bind.

Answer (score 1):

I personally like the IIFE, but "One man's garbage..." Anyway, you really just need to pass a copy of the number so that you don't get caught up in the closure variable.

```js
function test(){
  // Because you are working with a number and JavaScript passes all arguments by value
  // a copy of the number will be passed to helper, allowing helper to "disconnect"
  // from using the number in the parent scope
  return helper(Math.random()); 
  
  function helper(num){
    return function(){ console.log(num); }
  }
}

var a = test();
var b = test();

a(); //number
a(); //same as above
b(); //different number
b(); //same as above
```

Comment: Thank you for your input. I gave you a point. You demonstrated essentially the same process as CRice, but in oldschool javascript. Essentially there's no way to get rid of the closure and just explicitly state your scope without building scope with a wrapping function.

Comment: @adjenks That's correct and why I stated that you'll have to make a copy of the number.  You can't circumvent the fact that JavaScript is lexically scoped and lexical scope leads to closures.

Answer (score 1):

There's no need for the `printnum` function. Just return the inner anonymous function.

This is essentially the same as the PHP, but it doesn't need the `use()` declaration to list variables to inherit into the closure (PHP needs this because the default is to not allow any access to outside variables).

```js
function test() {
  var x = Math.random();
  return function() {
    console.log(x);
  }
}

var a = test();
var b = test();

a(); //number
a(); //same as above
b(); //different number
b(); //same as above
```

Comment: Thank you for the example. I forgot to use `this.x` in my example to demonstrate that I want to catch a variable at a certain state, and that variable might be static. I suppose you could just assign in to a new variable, like `var y = x;` and then use `y` in the function.

Comment: What is `this.x` supposed to be? There's no object involved in your code. Did you also mean to write `new test()`?

Comment: But if you use `new test()`, it returns the object, not the function. So it's not clear what you're really trying to do in the revised question.

Comment: Everything is an object in Javscript, ha. Okay well not everything, but functions are. I just gave it a static property for demonstration purposes. If you replaced var x with this.x in your example, it would repeat the same number 4 times.

Comment: What object do you think `this` refers to in your function? If you call `test()`, it refers to the global `window` object. You need to make the function a property of some object (or its prototype) and then call it as `someObject.test()`.

Comment: Or you can do something like `var a = test.call(someObject)` to pass an arbitrary context. But you need an object somewhere.

Comment: Ack. You're right, that made no sense. Been a long day... Anyhow, yes, call works, but I think I was looking for `bind()` like in dandavis' example.